# Yii2 + Stateless RESTful API + Mobile App: How to prevent abuse when app offers option to send verification via SMS

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, rest, yii2

I have built a mobile app using AngularJS/Ionic and website/api using Yii2. In my app I would like to have an option for users to request a verification code via SMS.

**Here's the app flow:**

1. User signs up on mobile app
2. API registers user, generates welcome email containing verification code and returns an access token; access tokens are valid for 14 days
3. User can request a new code via SMS

> My API is stateless and implements HTTPBearer and Basic auth, and rate
>   limiting. Currently, the rate limit is 75 calls in 10 minutes.

**So, here are my questions:**

1. Can I restrict access to my API to only allow calls made by my mobile app
2. What can be done to prevent API abuse and sending random phone numbers a SMS message?
3. How can I validate the phone number entered belongs to the user?

---

**The Problem:**
If API endpoints are discovered and supplied with valid credentials, SMS messages could be sent to any phone number. Also, from the app, a person can input any phone number and the SMS will attempt to be delivered to that number.

I have seen many apps offer a SMS feature, but I'm not sure how best to approach it.

I would really appreciate your thoughts on this.

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: any answers or solutions you found to this question